# How to change the class applied to a span in several elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing an application and I have several span. example:

```
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 1 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 2 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 3 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 4 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 5 </a>
```

I want to do the following through jQuery.

1) I want to change the class of one span when clicking without affecting the other span, so that something like this remains:

```
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-minus"> </ span> item 1 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 2 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 3 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 4 </a>
<a id="boton"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 5 </a>
```

2) I have the following code that implements but that implies repeating the code several times with different id, and I do not want that, I want to create a general function that does that.

```
$ ('# button'). click (function () {
 $ ('# span'). toggleClass ('glyphicon-minus');
});
```

Can you help me. *Thanks*

Comment: Why the `#span`? This is not how you set an ID

Comment: $ ('#button').click (function () {
 $ ('# span').first.attr('class',''glyphicon-minus'');
});

Comment: And as it would be I do not know much about css @Luca

Comment: Side note, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: When you say you want to change the class of ***one span***, does that always mean the first one, or could it be any?  Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: this of child should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may get the parent item of clickables and then set accordingly. You can check

[**Sample Code Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/Dipteedh/ya7xeo0t/1/).

```js
$ ('a'). click (function (event) {

var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "span" ) ) {
    target.toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');
  }
})
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a id="button" herf="#"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 1 </a>
<br />
<a id="button"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 2 </a>
<br />
<a id="button"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 3 </a>
<br />
<a id="button"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 4 </a>
<br />
<a id="button"> <span #span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"> </ span> item 5 </a>
```

In this code, event handled for anchor tag as in your HTML code, you do not have a unique id, or you can write the click event in the HTML itself.

```
$ ('a'). click (function (event) {
     var target = $( event.target );
     if ( target.is( "span" ) ) {
         target.toggleClass('glyphicon-minus');
     }
})
```

Hope it will help you.